# Binding from tabbed view to SharedUserDefaultsController proxy makes view unusable

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I need to create the GUI for setting my app preferences. Since I am not able to get multiple instances of the SharedUserDefaultsController in multiple storyboard scenes, I created a simple proxy for it. I'm trying to bind a text field content to a specific values of the SharedUserDefaultsController through the proxy which is represented in IB via an NSObject added to the scene that should contain the binding. For the binding I use self.defaults.values.default_key where default_key is a defined key in the StandardUserDefaults for my application.

When I try to show the view that contains the binding, though, it is not shown and the only displayed message in the console is

> Missing placeholder for identifier UpstreamPlaceholder-37m-v1-XT6

What am I doing wrong? In the storyboard source there's no trace of that identifier. Here's the code of the SharedUserDefaultsControllerProxy class that I created:

```
import Cocoa

class SharedUserDefaultsControllerProxy: NSObject{
    var defaults = NSUserDefaultsController.sharedUserDefaultsController()

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you making the binding in IB?  The shared user defaults controller should be available from a dropdown, so I'm not sure why you need a proxy.   Also, since the NSObject in the Nib is a top level object, you need to strongly retain it somewhere if the Nib isn't the NSMainNib, and I'm not sure how that works with storyboards.